# i face error to configuration android studio because of disable kotlin plugin . and software is not open .show start fail

Tags: android-studio

Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

```
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$EssentialPluginMissingException: Missing essential plugins: com.android.tools.design, org.jetbrains.android
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.checkEssentialPluginsAreAvailable(PluginManagerCore.java:750)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:843)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializeAndSetPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1047)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader$scheduleLoading$pluginSetDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(PluginDescriptorLoader.kt:397)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
D:\android studio\android-studio\jbr
```

I try many of time but it no solution arrive I try many times reinstall and delete all file. However, no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i face this issue too.
Then i uninstall android studio. my version is Android studio 2022.3.1.9 Giraffe.
After that i install the previous version. I install Android studio Electric Eel, and back normal again